# How many artifacts are there in Tap Titans 2?

Tags: tap-titans-2

http://tap-titans.wikia.com/wiki/Artifacts says only 30

Another says there are 83

Which one is right?

Comment: I have never played tap titans, but can you clarify your question? Your title says indicates your asking about tap titans 2, but is tagged for the first tap titan game. There appear to be separate wikis for the [first](http://tap-titans.wikia.com/wiki/Artifacts) game and [second](http://tap-titans-2.wikia.com/wiki/Artifact_List) game, listing 30 and 83 artifacts respectively

Comment: I mean tap titans 2. The reason the tag is tap titans is because there is no tag for tap titans 2. Also there is world 1 and world 2. I guess that no longer exist in tap titans 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tap titans 2 wiki is this one: http://tap-titans-2.wikia.com/wiki/Artifact_List

The link you have is the original tap titans. There are currently 83 artifacts in tap titans 2.

Comment: Currently we are at 95 artifacts

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s 95 but I mean the game could come out with more (post date is 8/29/2019)

[image: Screenshot of artifacts]

Answer (score -1):

There are 91 artifacts now in tap titans 2

Comment: Do you have a source?